# Luis build-in datetime entity not working in german culture

Tags: datetime, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I've created a LUIS app in **german (de-de)** culture.

I wanted to use the the build-in entity **datetime** (*datetimeV2* is not yet available in german culture) to extract the date information from the utterances.

Up to now, I had no luck in getting any date information. Or when luis detects datetime information, it's completly wrong:

[The german word 'rhetorik' is detected as datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spTXk.png)

[The month 'august' is not marked as datetime entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgv2H.png)

Is this because datetime is marked as deprecated? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-deprecated).

What should I do in my scenario?
I read that the datetime is extraced using the https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text project.

Should I parse the utterance with this library on my own after getting the luis results in my bot?

Or has somebody better experiance with datetime support in german culture with LUIS?

Comment: Please consider contributing to the project for datetimeV2 for German culture.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: I tried out the https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text with my failing examples from LUIS and they just work fine. So it seems like the Recognizer (with german culture) is already able to handle it. Maybe its LUIS with its deprecated datetime build-in entity type thats causing the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could preprocess the utterance with Recognizers-Text, get the date in German, send it on to LUIS for other predictions, then combine the two pieces of information in the client application?